# Headings and Chapters are messed up in ReadTheDocs Sphinx PDF file

Tags: pdf, latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, read-the-docs

For some reason, the subtitles become the chapters in the PDF generated for my docs by ReadTheDocs.

Check it out here: https://yarsaw.namantech.me/_/downloads/en/latest/pdf/

Here's the code for the index file

```
######################
**Welcome to YARSAW!**
######################

YARSAW is an open source, free and easy to use API Wrapper for the `Random Stuff API`_.


***************
Overview
***************

Features:

* Wraps all of the `Random Stuff API <https://api-info.pgamerx.com>`_
* Async-ready
* Easy to use
* Saves you a lot of time

*****************
Installation
*****************

To install the latest stable version of YARSAW, run the following command:

.. code-block:: bash

      python -m pip install yarsaw

To install a specific version of YARSAW, run the following command:

.. code-block:: bash

      python -m pip install yarsaw==<version>

To install the beta version of YARSAW, run the following command:

.. code-block:: bash

      python -m pip install git+https://github.com/BruceCodesGithub/yarsaw --upgrade



****************
Getting Started
****************

Get your API Keys
==================

1. Register to get an API Key at the `Random Stuff API resgistration page <https://api-docs.pgamerx.com/Getting%20Started/register/>`_. This is used for authentication.

2. Register at `RapidAPI <https://rapidapi.com/pgamerxdev/api/random-stuff-api>`_ for a RapidAPI Key and Account, and subscribe to the Random Stuff API. This is used to make requests to the Random Stuff API and keep track of them. You can go to `The RapidAPI Developer Dashboard <https://rapidapi.com/developer/apps>`_ after logging in, select an application, head over to security, and copy its key. This is your RapidAPI Key.

Examples
========

.. code-block:: python

      import yarsaw
      import asyncio # builtin, used for asynchronous calls

      client = yarsaw.Client("your_api_key", "your_rapidapi_key")

      async def joke():
         joke = await client.get_joke() # get the joke in form of a dict
         formatted_joke = yarsaw.Utils().format_joke(joke) # format the joke (optional)
         print(formatted_joke) # print the joke

      asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(joke()) # run the joke() function

Now just start reading the documentation!

****************
Contents
****************

.. tip::
   The :doc:`client` page contains all of the methods you can use to interact with the Random Stuff API, so we recommend reading that first.

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :caption: Documentation

   client
   utils
   
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 1
   :caption: Other Pages and Resources

   faq
   changelog

Documentation Last Updated on |today|
```

I want Welcome to YARSAW to be the first chapter, the next file to be the next. Instead, the subtitles become the chapters, and all the other content becomes subtitle.

I followed convention syntax from https://readthedocs.org/projects/documentation-style-guide-sphinx/downloads/pdf/latest/.

It works fine on the docs page itself (https://yarsaw.namantech.me).

Changing heading signs does not work.

Full code: https://github.com/BruceCodesGithub/yarsaw

Comment: Note: I have tried several methods including changing the heading symbols, but it didn't work. Using bold doesn't seem to be the problem either.

Comment: Do you see any errors or warnings in the build log? Try removing any cached build with `make clean` first, then rebuild. Do you have two index files, one for HTML and one for PDF output? You can look in `conf.py` and the file system. Finally for secondary headings, do not use overlines. Underlines is sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]
The problem was that the toctree was below headers, which caused issues. Moving to the top of the file solves it.